# Comparing consecutive records based on a column value in a data frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have a data frame which looks like this

```
df =  pd.DataFrame({'Shipment': ['Washington','Green Gala', 'Green Gala','Dale', 'Chiquita'],
                   'Source':  ['USA', 'SA','NZ', 'GU','EQ'],
                   'Serial No.': ['01','01','01','02','02'],
                   'Freight type':  ['Truck','Air','Sea','Sea','Sea'],
                   'Shipment date': ['2020-01-01','NULL','2020-01-02','2020-02-01','2020-02-01']})
```

[image: data frame df]

I want to find records where the serial number value is same but the shipment date and shipment values are different.

From the above example, for Serial No '01' Shipment has multiple rows which are Washington and Green Gala and the Shipment date is also different for all the 3 records, So I want to save these.

For Serial No '02', my Shipment is different but my Shipment date is Same, So I will ignore these.

My final data frame should look something like

```
df =  pd.DataFrame({'Shipment': ['Washington','Green Gala', 'Green Gala'],
                   'Source':  ['USA', 'SA','NZ'],
                   'Serial No.': ['01','01','01'],
                   'Freight type':  ['Truck','Air','Sea'],
                   'Shipment date': ['2020-01-01','NULL','2020-01-02']})
```

[image: final data frame]

Answer (score 0):

```
df.drop_duplicates(["Shipment date", "Serial No."], keep=False)
```

```
     Shipment Source Serial No. Freight type Shipment date
0  Washington    USA         01        Truck    2020-01-01
1  Green Gala     SA         01          Air          NULL
2  Green Gala     NZ         01          Sea    2020-01-02
```

Note: works for your sample input. just make sure if it works for all possible scenarios.